# Embed plotly plot as interactive not static on Wix

Tags: r, static, plotly, embed

So, I am creating a website on Wix (first time). I want to insert a plotly plot on the page so that when you hover your cursor over it, the figures appear. This is a very steep learning curve for me so go easy on me - the only code I've ever written is in R. I've managed to embed the figure and remove the "Edit chart" bit but it's still just a static plot.

I created a Chart Studio account. I saved the plot on it by including the following code in R:

```
Sys.setenv("plotly_username"="My username")
Sys.setenv("plotly_api_key"="My key")
api_create(plot, filename = "pltly_exmpl")
```

I went to Share then Embed then html on the https://chart-studio.plotly.com/create page. On Wix, I added the element by pasting the html code but adding `?showlink=false` to get rid of the Edit Chart. It works in that the plot is embedded but the whole point of using plotly was to make it interactive and it's not. How can I fix this?